# "connection failed" error for pg_cron extension

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, cron, pg-cron

Installed `pg_cron` and scheduled job, though there is connection error because job is not done and `cron.job_run_details` table shows `connection failed` error message.

As [doc](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) says:

> Important: Internally, pg_cron uses libpq to open a new connection to
> the local database. It may be necessary to enable trust authentication
> for connections coming from localhost in pg_hba.conf for the user
> running the cron job. Alternatively, you can add the password to a
> .pgpass file, which libpq will use when opening a connection.

Created file `.pgpass` with needed parameters, but not sure how to "tell" to libpq that for this user, for this host and DB read this `.pgpass` file.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear so - it **wasn't a file location/permissions issue as @PhilW. suggested? By all means, if you've found the answer to your problem - post it as an answer - I might even upvote it if it's good! :-)

Comment: @Vérace - Probably there was location/permissions issue for `.pgpass` file, but after little bit more googling, I found different solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I probably had `.pgpass` with wrong permissions  or wrong place (as @PhilW suggested) but I found completely different way which worked for me (btw, I just removed `.pgpass` file).

Solution was simply changing `cron.job.nodename` to empty string:

```
UPDATE cron.job SET nodename = '';
```

Source: https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/issues/48

Comment: `UPDATE cron.job SET nodename = '' where jobid=40;` --- jobid is vary with creating scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

> not sure how to "tell" to libpq that for this user, for this host and DB read this .pgpass file.

You don't need to.

The .pgpass file is *always* read when the account that "owns" it runs any postgres process that requires a password.
That ownership is determined by the file's location (i.e. in the account's home directory) and permissions (read/write to owner *only*).

The file contains host, database, username, etc. and the password to be used for each combination.  Postgres will extract and use the password found when all the other "bits" match what's being requested.

From [The Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq-pgpass.html), the file contains:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

So, for your HOST, DB and USER, you'd have something more like:

```
HOST:5432:DB:USER:password
```

Comment: "The .pgpass file is always read when the account that "owns" it runs any postgres process that requires a password."
This seems my problem, because I created file as Ubuntu admin user, but that DB process (cron job) is running by  `postgres` user

Comment: Read the Documentation (link in my reply) on how and where the Postgres Password File should be stored.  It sounds like either you've created it in the wrong place or with the wrong permissions (both are critical for the file to be used).